# Image disappearing when hiding then re-showing ListView

Tags: c++, qt, listview, blackberry-10

I'm currently working on part of an app which shows a news snippet next to an image (if an image exists). This list of news is part of a SegmentedControl "tab" page, and may be hidden and re-shown as required by the user. As the images are loaded over the network, they are handled by an ImageTracker and only set as a property once fully loaded.

The problem I'm having is that while these images load fine first time, these images then disapprear if I navigate away to a different SegmentControl "tab" and then navigate back to the News tab. The act of hiding is done by setting the visibility of non-active containers to false, and setting the visibility of the active container to true.

This is how I'm defining the data bindings:
    ListView {
        id: lstShowNews
        objectName: "lstShowNews"

```
    listItemComponents: [
        ListItemComponent {
            type: "item"      
            Detail_Tabs_NewsCell {
                newsHeadline: ListItemData.headline
                newsBlurbPreview: ListItemData.content
                newsTimeAdded: ListItemData.time    
                newsImageVisible: ListItemData.hasImage
                newsImage: ListItemData.image                              
            } 
        }
    ]
}
```

The aliases/properties for the custom list item:

```
property alias newsImageVisible: newsImage.visible
property alias newsHeadline: newsTitle.text
property alias newsImage: newsImage.image
property string newsBlurbPreview: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam condimentum tellus vel magna dapibus aliquam. Nunc iaculis metus ut arcu tempus semper."
property string newsTimeAdded: "News Source - 3 hours ago"
```

The section of C++ code that handles the loading of the list:

```
/*!
 * Handles loading for each tab page. Enables data to only be loaded on demand.
 * @param index - The new selected index on the SegmentedControl
 */
void MyClass::onSegmentChanged(int index) {
if(index == 2) {
    if(!mNewsLoaded) {
        // Load the news
        NewsRequester* news = new NewsRequester(mId);
        connect(news, SIGNAL(requestDone(QList<NewsItem*>)), this, SLOT(onNewsReceieved(QList<NewsItem*>)));
        indNews->start();         // Activity indicator
        news->requestNews();
    }
    else {
      // Caching functions
    }
}
else {
    // Stuff for other tabs
}
}

void MyClass::onNewsReceieved(QList<NewsItem*> newsItems) {
    qDebug() << "Received news reply";
    indNews->stop();
    indNews->setVisible(false);

    mNewsItems = newsItems;
    setNewsModel();

}

void MyClass::setNewsModel() {
GroupDataModel* newsModel = new GroupDataModel(QStringList() << "news");
newsModel->setGrouping(ItemGrouping::None);

// Move the list items to the data model
for(int i = 0; i < mNewsItems.size(); i++) {
    mNewsItems.at(i)->loadImage();
    newsModel->insert(mNewsItems.at(i));
}

ListView* lstNews = root->findChild<ListView*>("lstShowNews");
lstNews->setDataModel(newsModel);
}
```

Functionality for tracking the image and ensuring it's loaded properly before being passed to the list:

```
/*!
 * Tracks the status of the current local image and displays when ready
 */
void NewsItem::trackImage() {
// Load cascades image
mTracker = new ImageTracker(mLocalImage);
connect(mTracker, SIGNAL(stateChanged (bb::cascades::ResourceTracker::State)),
        this, SLOT(onStateChanged (bb::cascades::ResourceTracker::State)));
}

/*!
 * Passes the downloaded image's path to the list
 */

void NewsItem::onImageRetrieved(QString path) {
//qDebug() << "Received image " << path;
mLocalImage = QUrl(path);
trackImage();
}

/*!
 * Display the image if it's been fully loaded in memory
 */
void NewsItem::onStateChanged(bb::cascades::ResourceTracker::State state) {
if(state == bb::cascades::ResourceTracker::Loaded) {
    qDebug() << "Image loaded";
    mLocalCascadesImage = mTracker->image();
    emit localImageChanged();
}
}
```

Property for mLocalCascadesImage:

```
Q_PROPERTY(bb::cascades::Image image READ localImage NOTIFY localImageChanged)
```

Is there any reason as to why the ListView would misbehave in this way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. Turns out I also needed to expose the `newsImage.imageSource` property and pass it the path to the locally-cached version of the image, if available. While the `image` property is handy for ensuring images appear as soon as they have been downloaded, the `imageSource` property needs to be used for locally-available files.